# Joomla Component generating JS Error - function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla, gallery

so i have the issue, that i installed a gallery module/component in joomla ("
Unite Responsive Tile Gallery").

But this module didn't work. its keep getting me JS errors in my console that the function  "rtg" is not defined.

(example: http://bonesetterband.de/gallerie.html )

i would ask the maintainer/writer of the component, but it seems that's just me with this problem and i didn't get any easy help, so i just thought about asking here ;-)

so may there are some JQuery conflicts? if i change back to prostar theme, everything works fine. but i didn't find any differences in the templates which are explain this issue.

anybody a good idea what to check or to try?

thanks in advance

Comment: Just had a look at your script and is appears to be defined. It might be due to the fact your have 3 versions of jQuery being imported. 1 by Joomla (correct), 1 by your template and the other by the gallery module. If there is an option to remove jQuery within the module settings and also within your template, do so, as this might be causing a conflict

Comment: wow, that was great, didn't thought it was that easy. the template itself hadn't the option do disable jquery. but i found the corespondenting line of code and comment it out.seems to work pretty well. great. thanks a lot!

Comment: You're more than welcome. If you want to add it as an answer, feel free and accept it to mark it as solved

Comment: @Lodder mhh how did i do that :D ? i can only flag it, or "useful for question...etc"

Comment: There is a big text area below to type your answer. And there will be a "tick" icon on the left which you can click after 7 hours I believe

Comment: okay i will do in a few hours then ;-) thanks